# How do I write an identity transform in XSLT that preserves children of selected nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I've just begun using XSLT, and am becoming familiar with the identity template, thanks in large part to [Dimitre Novatchev,](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) who has provided some great answers on the topic.

I am performing an XML-to-XML transform, trying to isolate and copy out only a few elements of a large schema file. Here is a much-simplified version of the data:

**XSD Source**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">

<xsd:simpleType name="Alpha">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="1"/>
        <xsd:minInclusive value="0.0"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="100.0"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="Bravo">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Bravo data type.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="Charlie">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
        Charlie data type.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer"/>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="Delta">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
        Delta data type.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />   
<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="/ | node() | @*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*/node()[ 
                               not ( @name='Alpha')
                               and  
                               not ( @name='Charlie')
                                ]

                               "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The Results**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:simpleType name="Alpha"></xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="Charlie"></xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

This is really close, but I need the children of selected nodes Alpha and Charlie in the results, as if I had performed a `copy-of`.

**What I need**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:simpleType name="Alpha">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="1"/>
        <xsd:minInclusive value="0.0"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="100.0"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="Charlie">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Charlie data type.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Is there a way to select the elements with `copy-of,` or to specify in my `match` clause that I want to recurse into the children of Alpha and Charlie?

Thanks!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the actual cause and an easy correction. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse your logic into *copy all except for "Bravo" and "Delta" elements*.

The empty template will look like:

```
<xsl:template match="xs:simpleType[@name[.='Bravo' or .='Delta']]"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```

**Note**: Adding the namespace, just in case...

Another way, more semantic:

```
<xsl:template match="/*/*[not(@name[.='Alpha' or .='Charlie'])]"/>
```

Comment: Alejandro, thanks for the idea, but in the real application, I'm selecting a few items by name from hundreds of elements, and the elements I need can be simpleType, complexType, etc. So I need to specify Alpha and Charlie by name, rather than specifying what I don't want.

Comment: @MW Frost: Then you need to refactor the stylesheet. Check my update.

Comment: Alejandro, this works. I can make new templates for simpleType, complexType, etc. and use the same match clause in each: [not (@name[.='Alpha' or .='Charlie'])]

Comment: Your comment appeared before the update. Thanks for the /*/* code, since it obviates the need for separate templates.

Comment: @MW Frost: You are welcome. I'm glad you have figured out yourself.

Comment: @MW Frost: Do note that XML Schemas have their own semantic and you might have refered definitions outside the ones you want to preserve. That would end up in incomplete schema. There is also a solution for this.

Comment: +1 @user357812 Can you give links to the solution for preserving references to outside definitions. Just to complete the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Or, alternatively to the good answer by @Alejandro, you can fix the issues in your code**:

**Just change**:

```
<xsl:template match=
 "*/node()[
           not ( @name='Alpha')
          and
           not ( @name='Charlie')
           ]
  "/>
```

**to**:

```
<xsl:template match=
 "/*/node()[
           not ( @name='Alpha')
          and
           not ( @name='Charlie')
           ]
  "/>
```

**Explanation**: The originally provided "deletion template" is matching too-many nodes. It must only match children-elements of the top element.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the problem with my code. +1 and thanks to both of y'all.